# Python Script returns blank output

Tags: python

I have a script that needs to print out "found file" or "file not found" but unfortunately it returns a blank output and doesnt return either nor does it error out.

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta, date

# get the working directory 
dir_path = 'C:\temp\Memphis_SSES_Deliverable_HUS_20210201A_780122_rev'

# get current date
today = date.today()
formattedDate = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# search for file
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path + "/MACP"): 
    for file in files:  
        if file == "PACP_HUS_" + formattedDate + "A_780124.mdb": 
            print("found file")
    print("file not found")
```

Comment: Are you sure that directory exists? `os.walk` doesn't raise an exception unless you use the `onerror` kwarg

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  What values do root, dirs, files, and file have as your code executes?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to escape slashes in `dir_path`.

```
dir_path = 'C:\\temp\\Memphis_SSES_Deliverable_HUS_20210201A_780122_rev'
```

Or use a raw string

```
dir_path = r'C:\temp\Memphis_SSES_Deliverable_HUS_20210201A_780122_rev'
```

Also it will be a good idea to construct a path using `os.path.join` instead of concatenating strings with slashes, like you show in `os.walk` argument.
This would be more reliable:

```
os.path.join(dir_path, "MACP")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used an incorrect slash?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path + r"\MACP"):
```